# Lambda - user id in list existing in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

list1 contains userid and username

list2 contains userids

Need to display the list1 where its userid is included in list2.

```
string userids = "user1,user2,user3";
var list2 = userids.Split(',').Select(userid => userid.Trim()).ToList();

list1 = list1.Any(x => x.UserID)... //Got stuck here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use `HashSet<T>` for search:

```
string userids = "user1,user2,user3";
var userIdSet = new HashSet<string>(userids.Split(',').Select(userid => userid.Trim()));

list1 = list1.Where(x => userIdSet.Contains(x.UserID)).ToList();
```

Comment: You can nicely chain methods for creating `HashSet`: `userids.Split(',').ToHashSet()`.

Comment: @Fabio: requires the  .NET Framework 4.7.2 though. But didn't know, nice

Answer (score 3):

Another way is `Enumerable.Join` which is more efficient if the lists are pretty large:

```
var containedUsers = from x1 in list1
                     join x2 in list2 on x1.UserId equals x2
                     select x1;
list1 = containedUsers.ToList();
```

I assume that the UserID's in list2 are unique(otherwise use `Distinct`). If not, joining them might cause duplcicate items in `list1`.

Comment: I think having `HashSet` of values to search from will be more efficient.

Comment: @Fabio: not necessarily, because you have to fill this `HashSet` from the `string[]` before you can use it. In this time this query might already be finished. In most times it won't matter anyway, OP should use what he finds most readable.

Comment: Agree, didn't count HashSet building operation, thanks

Comment: Need to dig more: `Join` works in almost same way, it will loop one collection and create `Lookup` and will combined matches while looping another collection. So `Join` seems better approach since it wrap "implementation details" :)

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to get stuck on  So you need to check list2 contains the item you picked.

```
found = list1.Where( x => list2.contains(x.UserID));
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `Any` returns `bool`, it

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition
>
> **Return Value**
>
> Type: `System.Boolean`
>
> **true** if any elements in the source sequence pass the test in the specified predicate; otherwise, **false**.

Method `Where`

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

So you can use `Any` inside `Where` to filter only results that contains inside `list2`.

```
list1 = list1.Where(l1 => list2.Any(l2 => l2 == l1.UserID)).ToList();
```

References: **[Enumerable.Any(Of TSource) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**, **[Enumerable.Where(Of TSource) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)**